# OWA Exception message: Cannot submit message

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

One of our user was trying to send a message to two externals recipients from OWA. The message wasn't sent, and an error message popped up in top of the window :

```
Request
Url: https://xxx.lan:443/owa/ev.owa?oeh=1&ns=EditMessage&ev=Send
User host address: 192.168.x.x
User: DH IDA
EX Address: /o=xxx/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=dh.ida
SMTP Address: xxx@xxx
OWA version: 14.2.318.4
Mailbox server: xxxx

Exception
Exception type: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.InvalidRecipientsException
Exception message: Cannot submit message.

Call stack

à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.CoreItem.Submit(SubmitMessageFlags submitFlags) à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MessageItem.InternalSend(StoreObjectId saveSentMessageFolder, SubmitMessageFlags submitFlags) à Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Premium.EditMessageEventHandler.ProcessMessageRequest(MessageAction action)

Inner Exception
Exception type: Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionInvalidRecipients
Exception message: MapiExceptionInvalidRecipients: Unable to submit message. (hr=0x80004005, ec=1127) Diagnostic context: Lid: 55847 EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolSessionDoRpc called [length=46] Lid: 43559 EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolSessionDoRpc returned [ec=0x0][length=192][latency=0] Lid: 23226 --- ROP Parse Start --- Lid: 27962 ROP: ropSubmitMessage [50] Lid: 17082 ROP Error: 0x467 Lid: 27745 Lid: 21921 StoreEc: 0x467 Lid: 27962 ROP: ropExtendedError [250] Lid: 1494 ---- Remote Context Beg ---- Lid: 26426 ROP: ropSubmitMessage [50] Lid: 31297 Lid: 28033 StoreEc: 0x467 Lid: 31617 Lid: 4889 StoreEc: 0x467 Lid: 38787 StoreEc: 0x467 Lid: 1750 ---- Remote Context End ---- Lid: 26849 Lid: 21817 ROP Failure: 0x467 Lid: 60547 StoreEc: 0x467 Lid: 21966 Lid: 30158 StoreEc: 0x467 

Call stack

à Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32 hresult, SafeExInterfaceHandle iUnknown, Exception innerException) à Microsoft.Mapi.MapiMessage.SubmitMessageEx(SubmitMessageExFlags submitMessageExFlags) à Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.CoreItem.Submit(SubmitMessageFlags submitFlags)
```

It was working last week for the same recipients.

After some tests (send/receive internal/external messages) without any issue, I've started to googling it but found nearly nothing about this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing external recipients, I've found that one of them has a special character in his email addresse : 'ç' (not the case on the shown name in recipient field)!

OWA cannot just say something like "invalid recipient address" !?

Hope it can help someday.